# Filtering df on multiple columns from the same row in another table?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with start and end times for events (called df_time), and another dataset with when an event happened (df_val). I want to use df_time to filter down df_val only to events that happened within recorded time intervals.

I'm a bit lost on how to accomplish this though.

```
start = c(1, 5, 7, 4)
end = c(2, 7, 11, 7)
df_time = data.frame(start, end)

time = c(3, 6, 2, 10, 11)
val = c(100, 20, 30, 40, 50)
df_val = data.frame(time, val)

df_val %>% select_all() %>%
  filter(time >= df_time$start & time <= df_time$end)
```

Output:

```
  time val
1    6  20
Warning messages:
1: In time >= df_time$start :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In time <= df_time$end :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The above will run with warning messages (above), and gives me the wrong output (ignores starts/ends that are equal to value timestamps). Above, all values but 3 should be printed.

I'm unsure on how to fix this, and would appreciate any help/resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```r
library(tidyverse)
start = c(1, 5, 7, 4)
end = c(2, 7, 11, 7)
df_time = data.frame(start, end)

time = c(3, 6, 2, 10, 11)
val = c(100, 20, 30, 40, 50)
df_val = data.frame(time, val)

# return one row for each start/end pair that time falls between
map2_dfr(start, end, ~filter(df_val, time >= .x, time <= .y) %>% mutate(start = .x, end = .y))
#>   time val start end
#> 1    2  30     1   2
#> 2    6  20     5   7
#> 3   10  40     7  11
#> 4   11  50     7  11
#> 5    6  20     4   7

#return unique pairs
map2_dfr(start, end, ~filter(df_val, time >= .x, time <= .y)) %>% unique()
#>   time val
#> 1    2  30
#> 2    6  20
#> 3   10  40
#> 4   11  50

#simpler method, probably
df_val %>% filter(map_lgl(time, ~any((.x >= start) & .x <= end)))
#>   time val
#> 1    6  20
#> 2    2  30
#> 3   10  40
#> 4   11  50
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Edit: added some alternatives

Comment: It is! This answers my question, but I'm curious- let's say in addition to filtering to between two sets of time, I also needed to match an additional ID column (both df_time and df_val have a column called ID). Is there any way to accomplish in the method above?

Comment: sure, you could also just do something like `left_join(df_val, df_time, by = "id") %>% filter(time >= start, time <= end)`.  Without the id you could also do `crossing(df_val, df_time) %>% filter(time >= start, time <= end)` to get something similar to the first solution.  I probably wouldn't suggest `crossing` if the tables are very large, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using non-equi inner join using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_time)
setDT(df_val)

df_time[df_val, on=.(ID, start<time, end>time), nomatch=0L, 
    c(mget(paste0("x.", names(df_time))), mget(paste0("i.", names(df_val))))]
```

output:

```
   x.ID x.start x.end i.ID i.time i.val
1:    1       5     7    1      6    20
2:    1       4     7    1      6    20
3:    1       7    11    1     10    40
```